# Want to fetch a list of IDs from DB (The IDs are other than the auto assigned IDs in SQLite DB)

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Here is my fetch IDs function in DBAdapter class:
I want to fetch all the IDs and display the list in a toast message, cant understand where I am going wrong.

```
   public Cursor fetchAllIDs() {

         return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE0, new String[] {IDno1}, null, null, null, null,   null);
   }
```

Here is my function which I call on a button click and I want my toast to be filled with all IDs.

```
   private void fillData() {
       // Get all of the IDs from the database
          Cursor c = DBHelper.fetchAllIDs();
          startManagingCursor(c);

          String[] from = new String[] {DBAdapter.IDno1 };
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+from, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what error you are experiencing?

Comment: I am not getting the exact ID numbers the toast message displays something like: [Ljava.lang.String,@4058...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are returning a `Cursor` but then you never use the information in this `Cursor`.

Second, you cannot display a `String[]` as a string anyway. You'd have to loop through the `String[]` and display the values one by one.

You want something like this:

```
private void fillData() {
    Cursor c = DBHelper.fetchAllIDs();
    List<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            idList.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(IDno1)));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + idList.get(idList.size()-1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Edit: Fixed `getLong()` to `getString()`.

Comment: This is insightful, Ah how could I miss on that! But the problem now is that I get an error on: 
idList.add(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(IDno1))); it shows an error on the "IDno1" field. Do I have to supply that in quotes?

Comment: Oh, your "IDno1" field contains strings right? It should be `getString()`, not `getLong()`.

Comment: I don't know where you have defined `IDno1`. Maybe it should be `DBHelper.IDno1`, but you should be able to figure that out.